# How to call function right after getting permissions?

Tags: java, android-studio

After starting my application, I ask user for permissions with this function:

```
protected void requestPermission(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, 100);
        }
    }
```

I need to set checkboxes true or false right after getting user permissions, but if I call functions this way:

```
requestPermission();
setCheckboxStates();
```

function `setCheckboxStates()` activates before getting all the permissions. I could partly solve this problem with using `Thread.sleep()` but it doesn't work all the time and sometimes look weird.

How is it possible to call function `setCheckboxStates()` right after `requestPermission()` function finishes asking user for permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do **What you want to do** is to call this method in you activity named `onRequestPermissionsResult`...

This method respond right after the user permission Dialog...

As you just **put**... in the permission code above... this one...

```
protected void requestPermission(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, 100);
        }
    }
```

you send a number in this case was **100**... with that number you just passed, is the one you use in the `onRequestPermissionsResult`... to reconize which permission the user has just had... **HERE IS A EXAMPLE**

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {

            case 100:
                 --CODE HERE--
                break;
        }
    }
```

As I told you before, the number you pass is the same number you identify the permission here...

To find this method you can write it or just find it pressing **CTRL + O**

Answer (score 1):

The android system will inform you on the result of your permission request. After the user granted (or declined) the permission rights the method `onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)` is called to inform you.

[This tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#handle-response) explains handling permission request quite good.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the function `requestPermission( );` and `requestPermissions( );` is different, am i right?, and the logic, if `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, 100); }` were success it would call `requestPermissions( );` then `setCheckBoxStates( );`  with the value of true, if not it will be false..so it would be like this `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, 100); 
setCheckBoxStates(true);}  else {setCheckBoxStates(false);}`